# AngularJS ui-select - not selecting option on dropdown

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-formly, ui-select, angular-ui-select

I have ui-select element used with help angular-formly field type. I have defintion like this:

```
<ui-select ng-model="model[options.key]" theme="bootstrap" ng-required="{{to.required}}" ng-disabled="{{to.disabled}}" reset-search-input="false">,
   <ui-select-match placeholder="{{to.placeholder}}">,
        {{$select.selected[to.labelProp || \name\]}},
    </ui-select-match>,
    <ui-select-choices group-by="to.groupBy" repeat="option[to.valueProp || \value\] as option in to.options | filter: $select.search">,
        <div ng-bind-html="option[to.labelProp || \name\] | highlight: $select.search"></div>,
    </ui-select-choices>,
</ui-select>
```

I am looking for a way to turn off filtering, turning off type ahead option, so this element would act more like regular select with its look.

Also when feed with value - via model - when clicked to expand selection on list become not in synch with value - it is selecting first value on list instead value driven by model - when "clicked away" goes to normal. Is it a setting for it ?

Answer (score 0):

Use UI Bootstrap **Typeahead** feature. Hope it is lightweight and easy.

```
<div class='container-fluid typeahead-demo' ng-controller="TypeaheadCtrl">
    <h4>Static arrays</h4>
    <pre>Model: {{selected | json}}</pre>
    <input type="text" ng-model="selected" uib-typeahead="state for state in states | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" class="form-control">
</div>
```

In your controller, have a states array.

Comment: Thank you for your response - I am looking for something opposite - turning off type ahead